# Facebook graph api bulk query for gender

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to query the gender for all of a user's friends using the graph API?

Answer (score 1):

You have to send a request to `/user_id/friends` and then iterate through the data set send a request to `/friend_id?fields=gender` for each friend.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USERID/friends/?fields=gender
```

You'll need to pass your access token, of course, but you can include any extra fields you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you will have to query for the friends first, run through the ids and query for the gender:

so something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/ID/friends?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN
```

then for each id:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/SECOND_ID?fields=gender
```

Comment: I wonder if you can use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ ?  I haven't looked at it really

Comment: I think you could do this with something like `SELECT uid, gender FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

Comment: haven't successfully used your method (having some weird issues that are unrelated I think) but I would point out that you should use 'sex' and not 'gender' :D

Comment: Yeah haha good find, `sex` in FQL and `gender` in Graph API... Nice and consistent, eh? ;)